# entity framework mysql connection string error?

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder
            .UseMySql(@"server=localhost;port=3306;database=shopDb;user=root;password=mysql123;");
            
        }
```

I am trying to connect entity framework and mySQL. Why i get this error? (Cannot convert 2 arguments from 'string' to 'MicrosofEntityFrameworkCore.ServerVersion')

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmOHt.jpg)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your connection string. Try to remove a port since you are using a local host.